# paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished: is returning an empty queue when it should have transactions in it

Tags: objective-c, ios, storekit

This is my first time using Store Kit and everything has gone great up until I attempt to restore purchases. I've seen several other posts on stack overflow about similar issues but I've not found a solution that works for me.

I have a button in my app that calls `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`. This in turn triggers the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` method `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:`. The problem is that `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` has zero transactions in the returned queue.

If I then attempt to make the purchase I am notified that I have already made the purchase. This tells me that the store knows that my test Apple ID has successfully made the purchase on a previous attempt. Why then does `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` return an empty transactions collection on it's queue?

There has been some mention of the sandbox behaving erratically but I need to see this working before I go live to the AppStore.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you handling the transactions in `-paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`?  This callback gets your restored transactions before the `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` callback.

You should do your restore processing and handling inside `-paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`.

Comment: I am handling restores in both methods. The strangest thing ended up fixing my problem. I created a new test user in itunesconnect and the new user behaves as expected. For some reason my first test user is unable to restore purchases.

Comment: That's disconcerting.  I hope real-world accounts don't act like this.

Comment: I've experienced the EXACT same thing. Was pulling my hair out for two days, turned out something dodgy wrong with the test users I was using. Created a new test user, then its all good.

Comment: Happened to me as well. Except all I had to do is create a new user, and then the old user started working. Apple's Sandbox is terribly unstable.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. This one test account will not restore all transactions. Creating a new account works perfectly. This is very unnerving.

Comment: And I just had this problem too. Newly created test user can restore transactions correctly, old test user cannot. The old one used to work, so I'm not sure what happened. Unnerving, indeed.

Comment: In my case, newly created users don't make a difference.  no users are able to restore transactions.  I get a blank transaction array in paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished every time for every user.  And paymentQueue:updatedTransactions is never called upon restoration.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is a bug with the sandbox App Store. My restores were not working with my test accounts (created in the iOS 5.0 era). `-paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` was not getting called during a restore.

As suggested by **process255**'s comment, I created a new test user in iTunes Connect. With the new test account, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It **depends upon the product type** the which products will be queued back in:

```
-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

as an alternate, read the receipt at:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]
```

only problem with the receipts is that they are stored locally, but apple don't keeps it hanging .. ofcourse the purchases are saved on the apple server too. Refresh /  load the receipt by:

```
    SKReceiptRefreshRequest *recreq = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
[recreq start];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but instead of creating a new user, I just went to iTunes & Aoo Stores in Settings and logged out of the sandbox test account and tried it again.  Working!